# Packages not added to channel automatically repository sync

Tags: spacewalk

I've created a spacewalk server for package management on RHEL instances. I've created a channel and a repository. In the channel repositories I have associated the repo with the channel. However when I run the sync packages are shown as not being in a channel unless I manually add them. How can I get them to add automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the architecture settings were incorrect in the channel. Changing to x86_x64 sorted the issue